# Split C Array on element

Tags: c, arrays, split, predicate

Say, I have an array `T*array` and a predicate `p`, I want to split the array into different sub-arrays `T**subs` on every element matching `p`.

So something like:

```
typedef bool (*P) (T element);
T**subs(T*array,P p){....}
```

How can the code for `subs()` look like?

Note, that the code is just pseudo code, you can use variables like `array_length` and so on in your example, because I just want to get the idea on how to implement `subs()`.

Comment: `array` is pointer not an array, namely a pointer to `T`. Same for `subs`, it's a pointer to a pointer to `T`, not an array.

Comment: arrays are technically pointers in C

Comment: Well, so you then surely can tell us from just looking at `array` how many elements it has, couldn't you?

Comment: read the question again, please :)

Comment: Would `subs()` be allowed to copy the elements for any sub-array detected?

Comment: The main problem is how to indicate the end or the size of any sub-array.

Comment: `int*sublength`

Comment: sublength[0] is the count of  subarrays and sublength[1-n] is the length of them

Comment: Those subarrays could of different size, right?

Comment: yes in almost all scenarios there are of different size each

Comment: Sure, passing a pointer to a counter is the most straight forward way to solves this. But it's avoidable. ;-)

Comment: How do you know the size of the input array?

Comment: To me the question sounds as if you want new arrays for each sub-array. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We call that a *callback function*, not *predicate*.

```
typedef bool (*P) (T element);

T * * subs(T * array, P callback) {
    T * * retval = malloc(sizeof(T*) * max_groups); // either count before, or realloc as needed
    size_t group = 0;
    retval[group] = array;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
        if (callback(array[i])) {
            retval[++group]=array + i;
        }
    }

    return retval;
}
```

This reuses the memory of the argument `array` and doesn't return any information about the lengths of the groups, but since you only wanted a general idea on how to solve this, I think this should be enough starting point for you to get exactly what you want.

Comment: and how can I get the size of the result array?

Comment: ok, thank you, but it would also be nice to know the size of the individuals, could you please add a `int*size` variable, so that size[0] is the count of subs and size[1 to n] is the individual size of all subarrays, thanks a lot!

Comment: it's a little more work than just to add an int, because in this example i just grab the pointers of the array argument and place them in a new array (or in other words, I just return pointers pointing to the starts of the groups). But you can easily add a retval[++group] = malloc(...) and then realloc that one. then you need one additional line retva[group][k++] = array[i]. k will be your retval[group][0] element, if that is an int.

Comment: Thank you, but I already found a smarter solution: Making this `int*size` and  `int size_len`, then always incrementing the last element of size and when hitting semicolon, size[size_len++]=0

Comment: Whatever you see fit solves your problem is a good solution ;)

Answer (score 3):

Of more importance than "what would the code look like" is the question "what data structure do you want/need to use?"

For example, if you need to change the sub arrays without changing the original values, you need to copy the array elements into new arrays. If you do not change the values of the sub arrays, you can just return an array of pointers or indices into the original array. Or the array of pointers is a list.

Once you have decided on a data structure that matches your requirements, you can develop the algorithm. But if your algorithm turns out to be cumbersome or slow, you might need to adapt your data structure to allow faster processing.

So you see, your question needs a lot of "design" and decissions from you, based on your requirements.

Comment: No at no time any of them will be changed.

Comment: Its kinda immutable

Comment: So that is one of your decissions. Just continue thinking...I'll not give you a (code) answer.

Comment: thank you, this is very nice to not give a code answer on a coding q&a forum - i will upvote this :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there will be no gaps between the sub-arrays, you can return a pointer to a dynamically created array `T * result` with size `N` for `M=N-2` detected elements.

This array needs to be `NULL` terminated to indicate it's size, that is `result[N-1]` needs to be `NULL`.

Each element of `result` points into the source `array` indicating the start (the 1st element) of a sub-array.

The `result[N-2]` points just beyond the last element.

The size of sub-array `i` (for *i = {`0` ... `M`}*) can then be derived by doing `result[i+1]-result[i]`.

No copying, no additional array to indicated the sub-arrays' sizes is needed. Just the source array's size needs to be passed to `subs()`.

Comment: @einmensch: If we can assume that the last sub-array's last element is always the last element of the source array, this approach would also work with N=M-1 elements being returned.

Comment: @einmensch: If there may be gaps between the sub-arrays you need to return N=(2*M)+1 elements and indicate the sub-arrays' end separately. So the even indices return the start of a sub-array and the odd indices mark their end.